# How to get a control to update

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am creating a button that when you push it, it takes the value of a date field (represented on a form) and adds a number to it.  Upon adding the number, the result should be represented in another date field (represented on the form): In short, I am trying to create a button that adds 7 days to a start date calculating the finish date depending on how many weeks the user chooses (how many times he pushes the button).  What I can get my head around is how get the second date on the form to update immediately.  I have tried me.refresh and me.requery but this does not work. Furthermore, on occasion (not Always) i  get an unexpected "save / copy / ignore message" telling me that the data is already in use by another user.

Also, it seems there is an overly long delay. You can run the code several times and nothing happens. If you wait (literally 5 minutes), the error message comes up. As soon as you close the error message, the form updates correctly.

I have been Learning programming for a while now but this aspect of getting forms to update swiftly i still cant seem to get my head around. Below is my code:

```
Private Sub Comando36_Click()

 If ObjectivesDialNumber.Value = 1 Then
    ObjectivesDialNumber.Value = 2
    Me.imgDue.Visible = True
    Me.imgTre.Visible = False
    Me.imgQuattro.Visible = False
    Me.imgCinque.Visible = False
    Me.imgSei.Visible = False
    Me.imgUno.Visible = False
    Me.lblNextReview.Caption = "weeks"


    st_sql = "UPDATE tblProjectMasterList SET tblProjectMasterList.NextReviewDateObjectives = [tblProjectMasterList].[LastReviewDateObjectives]+14"
    Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_sql)

ElseIf ObjectivesDialNumber.Value = 2 Then
    ObjectivesDialNumber.Value = 3
    Me.imgDue.Visible = False
    Me.imgTre.Visible = True
    Me.imgQuattro.Visible = False
    Me.imgCinque.Visible = False
    Me.imgSei.Visible = False
    Me.imgUno.Visible = False
    Me.lblNextReview.Caption = "weeks"

    st_sql = "UPDATE tblProjectMasterList SET tblProjectMasterList.NextReviewDateObjectives = [tblProjectMasterList].[LastReviewDateObjectives]+21"
    Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_sql)

ElseIf ObjectivesDialNumber.Value = 3 Then
    ObjectivesDialNumber.Value = 4
    Me.imgDue.Visible = False
    Me.imgTre.Visible = False
    Me.imgQuattro.Visible = True
    Me.imgCinque.Visible = False
    Me.imgSei.Visible = False
    Me.imgUno.Visible = False
    Me.lblNextReview.Caption = "weeks"

    st_sql = "UPDATE tblProjectMasterList SET tblProjectMasterList.NextReviewDateObjectives = [tblProjectMasterList].[LastReviewDateObjectives]+28"
    Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_sql)

ElseIf ObjectivesDialNumber.Value = 4 Then
    ObjectivesDialNumber.Value = 5
    Me.imgDue.Visible = False
    Me.imgTre.Visible = False
    Me.imgQuattro.Visible = False
    Me.imgCinque.Visible = True
    Me.imgSei.Visible = False
    Me.imgUno.Visible = False
    Me.lblNextReview.Caption = "weeks"

    st_sql = "UPDATE tblProjectMasterList SET tblProjectMasterList.NextReviewDateObjectives = [tblProjectMasterList].[LastReviewDateObjectives]+35"
    Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_sql)

ElseIf ObjectivesDialNumber.Value = 5 Then
    ObjectivesDialNumber.Value = 6
    Me.imgDue.Visible = False
    Me.imgTre.Visible = False
    Me.imgQuattro.Visible = False
    Me.imgCinque.Visible = False
    Me.imgSei.Visible = True
    Me.imgUno.Visible = False
    Me.lblNextReview.Caption = "weeks"

    st_sql = "UPDATE tblProjectMasterList SET tblProjectMasterList.NextReviewDateObjectives = [tblProjectMasterList].[LastReviewDateObjectives]+42"
    Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_sql)

ElseIf ObjectivesDialNumber.Value = 6 Then
    ObjectivesDialNumber.Value = 1
    Me.imgDue.Visible = False
    Me.imgTre.Visible = False
    Me.imgQuattro.Visible = False
    Me.imgCinque.Visible = False
    Me.imgSei.Visible = False
    Me.imgUno.Visible = True
    Me.lblNextReview.Caption = "week"

    st_sql = "UPDATE tblProjectMasterList SET tblProjectMasterList.NextReviewDateObjectives = [tblProjectMasterList].[LastReviewDateObjectives]+7"
    Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_sql)

  End If


End Sub
```

Comment: might try DoEvents() when you are ready to make the GUI update

Comment: This is getting stranger. When I run the code the field doesnt update. As soon as i open the table to check if it worked and confirm that the query updated, i get the error message "save/copy/dont save". As long as i choose dont save, the form then updates correctly when the table is closing.

Comment: no, DoEvents allows the OS to process events that may be waiting on your code.  Similar Q/A here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584046/yield-control-to-ms-access-to-update-gui-and-process-form-events

Comment: Sorry i am having trouble with the syntax.  Does DoEvents go at the end of the code alone?

Comment: Just type DoEvents on the line before you end the sub. That way, if any of your if-blocks were hit, and controls' visibility or captions changed, those changes should be allowed to be painted

Comment: Ok, that is done but the situation is this now. Upon running the code, I wait literally 5-10 seconds and then the screen flashes and the error message comes. I select "do not save" and immediately the record updates.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give this a try, or try adding me.repaint to your code.

```
 Private Sub Comando36_Click()


On Error GoTo Comando36_err
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim lrd As Integer
Set db = CurrentDb

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Select * From tblProjectMasterList")




    Me.imgDue.Visible = False
    Me.imgTre.Visible = False
    Me.imgQuattro.Visible = False
    Me.imgCinque.Visible = False
    Me.imgSei.Visible = False
    Me.imgUno.Visible = False
    Me.lblNextReview.Caption = "weeks"





 Select Case ObjectivesDialNumber.Value

    Case 1
        ObjectivesDialNumber.Value = 2
        Me.imgDue.Visible = True
        lrd = 14




    Case 2
        ObjectivesDialNumber.Value = 3
        Me.imgTre.Visible = True
        lrd = 21


    Case 3
        ObjectivesDialNumber.Value = 4
        Me.imgQuattro.Visible = True
        lrd = 28


    Case 4
        ObjectivesDialNumber.Value = 5
        Me.imgCinque.Visible = True
        lrd = 35


    Case 5
        ObjectivesDialNumber.Value = 6
        Me.imgSei.Visible = True
        lrd = 42


    Case Else
    ObjectivesDialNumber.Value = 1
        Me.imgUno.Visible = True
        Me.lblNextReview.Caption = "week"
        lrd = 7

End Select

rs.Edit
rs![NextReviewDateObjectives] = DateAdd("d", lrd, rs![LastReviewDateObjectives])
rs.Update
rs.Close

Me.Refresh
Me.Repaint

Comando36_Exit:
    Exit Sub

Comando36_err:
MsgBox Error$
```

I hope it helps. I certainly have been given a lot of help over the years.